# Setting up multiprocessing program elongate execution time when it is light-load CPU-Bound?

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing, multicore

I am trying to utilise my processor's multicores in speeding up NumPy calculations, but instead the code slows down when setting up the `multiprocessing.Pool()`, is this because the load is trivial compared to the time setting up the threads?

Here is the code I am trying to accelerate using `multiprocessing`:

```
import multiprocessing as mps
from time import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x,y):
        return np.sin(x)+np.cos(y)-x*y

if __name__=="__main__":

    x = np.arange(-10,10,0.01); y = x
    with mps.Pool(4) as pool:
        start = time()
        x, y = pool.apply(np.meshgrid,(x,y))
        z = pool.apply(f,(x,y))
        plt.contour(x,y,z)
        print("Took: {} seconds".format(time()-start))
        plt.show()
```

With `multiprocessing.Pool()` the operation takes about 2.4 seconds, while without takes about 0.78 seconds.

Comment: `Pool.apply()` blocks until the result is ready, so you're not really doing parallel processing — just introducing overhead.

Comment: Also your function `f` is pretty short. So you wouldn't see any benefit from multi-processing, instead just adding overhead. Make it more complex or add a delay to test multiprocessing.

Comment: so I should replace `Pool.apply` with `Pool.map` or `Pool.apply_async`? @RaJa
Yeah I think so too it is short, but I am just new to multiprocessing and trying to figure things out,

Comment: You should be able to use `apply_async()` to get concurrency.  `map_async()` is also often a good choice depending on exactly what you're doing.

Comment: If you try to figure it out, don't start timing yet. Try to understand what is going on, before you start optimizing for better time performance. Unfortunately, I don't use `Pool`. Instead I do everything manually. So I can't really help you with that.